# Qt exception handling - try catch

Tags: c++, qt, error-handling, try-catch

I working with qt, I have a big project with gui and several threads.

I want to add exaption handling.
I googled it and didn't find any tutorial or some relevant answer.

In some sites I read that qt not support try catch.

Is qt support try catch? Or some error handling?
If yes, can some one give some direction or tutorial?

Tank you.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to throw an exception through a signal-slot invocation. Everything else you want to do with exceptions in a Qt application is allowed.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html#signals-and-slots

> Throwing an exception from a slot invoked by Qt's signal-slot
>   connection mechanism is considered undefined behaviour, unless it is
>   handled within the slot.

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void mySlot()
    {
        throw std::logic_error(""); // Undefined behavior when invoked by a signal
    }
};
```